# Access VBA code in report gives the same result for each row

Tags: vba, ms-access

This is my report:

[image]

I have coded in VBA so that the 3rd column (texbox) shows the ID related to each `MinDeNote`.
But it just shows `3` for all row.
`3` is the ID of the first product, not all of them.
How could I do to make a loop? Thanks !

This is my code:

```vb
Me!Texte7 = DLookup("F_Code", "Query", "Note = """ & [MinDeNoteBox] & """")
```

The outcome is gonna be different for each row, which is not the case now.

Comment: Try put your code into Private Sub Detail_Format(Cancel As Integer, FormatCount As Integer)
  Me!Texte7.value = DLookup("F_Code", "Query", "Note = """ & [MinDeNoteBox] & """")
End Sub

Comment: @jacouh I actually wrote this code under ''on load'' of the report. I wrote it like this: Private Sub Report_Load(Cancel As Integer, FormatCount As Integer) but it gives me an error

Comment: On Each detail section, one has a different [MinDeNoteBox].

Comment: Each P_Code has a different ''MinDeNote''. Therefore the third column in the report should recall different ID for each P_Code. I'm not sure what i can change in my code.

Comment: You have a query named "Query"? Advise to give objects more informative names.

Comment: I did what you said. Control souce = DLookup("F_Code", "Queryname", "Note = ' " & [MinDeNoteBox] & " ' "). It says that there is an error in the writting, any ideas? MinDeNoteBox is numeric maybe thats the problem? Thanks !

Comment: If field is numeric, don't use apostrophe delimiters for parameter. Date/Time field uses # delimiter. So Note field is number type?

Comment: ive changed it to = DLookup("F_Code", "query1", "Note =   [MinDeNoteBox]  ")since its numeric and there still is a syntax error

Comment: Parameter must be concatenated, as it was before. MinDeNote looks like a calculated field.

Comment: = DLookup("F_Code", "EssaiElo", "Note =  & [MinDeNoteBox] & ") isnt valid either. syntax error again.

Comment: `= DLookup("F_Code", "EssaiElo", "Note = " & [MinDeNoteBox])`. What data type is Note?

Comment: If expression works in VBA to return value of 3, it should work in textbox.

Comment: Note is an equation ([F_Flexibilite]*0.058)+([F_Fiabilite]*0.129). Don't worry i've tried to replace note by the equation too. doesnt work. I'Ve just tried = DLookup("F_Code", "EssaiElo", "([F_Flexibilite]*0.058)+([F_Fiabilite]*0.129) =  " & [MinDeNoteBox] )

Comment: exactly if it works in vba it should in control source. but it doesnt, i copied pasted it and it says syntax error

Comment: I couldn't duplicate the problem.  Other than an extra "  which I removed I got your code to work.  So here is a possibility: When queries get complicated Access eventually bugs so try the following.  turn all necessary final queries  into tables and base your report on those.  The designer has a make table option which makes this easy.  Otherwise yelp and I'll post the working example.